# Insert string with Quotes into Oracle with PHP

Tags: php, oracle

I am trying to insert into an Oracle table from PHP a string containing single or double quote. **"Test"** or **Test's**

I am using oci8 and oci_bind_by_name to bind values.

```
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':hName', $value);
```

I also tried specify the defaults:

```
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':hName', $value, -1, SQLT_CHR);
```

I tried PHP function before send it like:

```
addslashes();
str_replace("'", "''", $string);  //To scape single quotes.
```

But every time I look the table the string has this value:

```
&#34;Test&#34;
```

When I insert from SQL Developer

```
INSERT INTO table (notes) VALUES (:notes);
```

SQL Developer prompt to enter *notes* value, I enter *"Test"* and when I look this new inserted row the value is correct with double quote:

```
"Test"
```

And no like the PHP

```
 &#34;Test&#34;
```

Thanks in advance.

[SQL Developer result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5siwA.jpg)

Comment: wierd, ascii 34 is double quotes -- where do you see the $#34, is it from sql developer?  when you do your select, select dump(column name) and it will give you the asciis, add that to your post

Comment: Hi Peter, I see it when I do the Select query in SQL Developer, also I have an Angular app that when I query with PHP and return to Angular it shows to the user the same I saw in the SQL Developer query. (&)#34;Test(&)#34;

Comment: so -- I wonder if it is a character set issue -- is the db on a different server than the server running the PHP

Comment: can you do this -- select dump(notes) from test_table; -- and post the results

Comment: Yes, the DB is in a different server than the PHP server. Result:
Typ=1 Len=14: 38,35,51,52,59,84,101,115,116,38,35,51,52,59

Comment: I am connecting using this: oci_pconnect('user', 'passwd', '192.168.0.3:1521/TEST', 'AL32UTF8');

Comment: wow, check it out, go to asciitable.com, it has put in the ampersands and pound signs as separate characters.  E.g. 38=&, 35=#

Comment: Thanks Peter, I am seeing what you recommend, then it makes me think is passed as literal character to the function in charge to insert in the DB. I reviewed the PHP side and data is going through  a validation process before send it to the DB. filter_input(INPUT_POST, $var, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); So this PHP sanitation is converting all the Quotes HTML code & #34; to literal character. I turn off the validation process and data was correctly inserted into the DB.  Once again thank you for your help !